# Remove all padding of a select box

Tags: html, css

I've been creating a form and I've had a problem with the padding of a select box.

I wrote some of my code in JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/fsrx4rjh/5/).

I need remove all padding of the select box, but the problem is this:

[image: Select box with padding 0]

The select box has extra padding. I've tried it with margin, but not work. This happen with *Chrome*, *Mozilla* and *Explorer* browsers.

```css
select {
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
Room password
<select>
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: a simple quesiton : why you need this ? did you think about UX/UI ?

Comment: which padding are you taking about? Is there a sample of how you would like it to look?

Comment: @TemaniAfif : to concentrate the maximum amount of controls on a single window in a desktop environment. UX: people have pain scrolling 3000 times a day to reach datas not in view because select adds unnecessary padding (in this case). UI: the work is meant for people who manipulates tons of datas in a reactive way, not chilling people on their smartphone. Also UI: some datas are better handled via specialized features (eg: combos with range bars). So an entire redesign CSS+JS without using select is MUCH easier and efficient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Add another css propertie like here display, if you don't like previous answear of reducing width from 100%, because it wasn't' stack one under another

```css
select {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
Room password
<select>
      <option>No</option>
      <option>Yes</option>
    </select>
```